# C++ Python import class; call methods

Tags: c++, python, python-c-api

I am using Python 2.7. It is not clear to me how to embed Python inside C++ as found here: http://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/embedding.html.

I have a simple python example here in a file named test.py:

```
class math:
    #def __init__(self):
    def add(self, num1, num2):
        return num1 + num2

    def subtract(self, num1, num2):
        return num1 - num2
```

From python, I would do something like this:

```
>>> from test import math
>>> m = math()
>>> a = m.add(1, 2)
>>> s = m.subtract(1, 2)
```

I have the beginning of some C++ code to do this:

```
PyObject *pName, *pModule;
Py_Initialize();
pName = PyString_FromString("test");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
```

That seems to work just fine. But, that seems to be the equivalent of doing this in Python:

```
import test
```

How do I import the Python class math?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a quick n' dirty example in C which does the equivalent of...

```
>>> import mymath
>>> m = mymath.math()
>>> print '1 + 2 = %d' % m.add(1, 2)
```

Note that I've renamed the module from `test` to `mymath` because there's a module called `test` in the standard Python library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

int main()
{
    setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);

    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* module = PyImport_ImportModule("mymath");
    assert(module != NULL);

    PyObject* klass = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "math");
    assert(klass != NULL);

    PyObject* instance = PyInstance_New(klass, NULL, NULL);
    assert(instance != NULL);

    PyObject* result = PyObject_CallMethod(instance, "add", "(ii)", 1, 2);
    assert(result != NULL);

    printf("1 + 2 = %ld\n", PyInt_AsLong(result));

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

...which outputs...

```
$ gcc foo.c -lpython2.7 && ./a.out
1 + 2 = 3
```

However, if you do any major amount of work with the Python/C API between `Py_Initialize` and `Py_Finalize`, you'll have to watch your reference counts, and use `Py_INCREF` and `Py_DECREF` when appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Works exactly as expected. The only thing I did different is not include the setenv() call. This does not seem to be available in MSVS 2008 c++, or, I did not know where to find it. The test ran fine without it.

Comment: @DooDah Sounds like your module was already in the `PYTHONPATH` then. I had problems importing from the current working directory on Ubuntu without the `setenv` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a class, but you can import a file or library (as is true with most languages?) - which is just what you did here in the case of test.py.

Comment: The question was how to import a python class into C++. The answer marked as correct is the solution.